# Receiving 'Max retries exceeded from URL' error when requests is set to 1 per 30 seconds (required by target website robot.txt)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape www.eliteprospects.com, a hockey statistics website that has player statistics for junior (16-20) players.  When I run the python script I am getting errors that I cannot find a solution for.

I have read through as many of the previous Stackoverflow questions related to 'Max retries exceeded with url' and none of them seem to fit my particular issue.  The website I am trying to scrape, www.eliteprospects.com, has a robot.txt page with requests limited to 1 per 30 second.  I have put in a sleep(30) line in my code after my requests.get(url) call and am still receiving the error.

Of the previous questions on stackoverflow, many of them are related and sometimes very similar to my problem but when I implement any of the solutions that are offered I keep getting these same errors.

I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong, is it my code? Is it the website?  Did I run the crawler with too many requests early on and get banned? Is there something in my for loops that I cannot see because I have been staring at it too long? I have no idea....  Please help.

Cheers,

The error(s) that I am getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\TPCal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\TPCal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\TPCal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\TPCal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\TPCal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\TPCal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0E241110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.elitepospects.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /league/whl/stats/2005-2006?sort=tp&page=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0E241110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Analytics/EliteProspects/EliteProspects.py", line 42, in <module>
    headers = headers)
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Analytics\EliteProspects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.elitepospects.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /league/whl/stats/2005-2006?sort=tp&page=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0E241110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

My python script...

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import time
from time import sleep
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from warnings import warn
import pandas as pd


leagues = ['whl', 'ohl', 'qmjhl']
leagues_url = [str(i) for i in leagues]
seasons = ['2005-2006', '2006-2007', '2007-2008', '2008-2009', '2009-2010',
           '2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015',
           '2016-2017', '2017-2018']
seasons_url = [str(i) for i in seasons]
pages = [str(i) for i in range(1, 5)]

players = []
games_played = []
goals = []
assists = []
penalty_minutes = []
plus_minus = []

start_time = time()
requests = 0

for league in leagues_url:
    for season in seasons_url:
        for page in pages:
            response = get('http://www.elitepospects.com/league/'
                           + league
                           + '/stats/'
                           + season
                           + '?sort=tp&page='
                           + page)
            sleep(30)
            requests += 1
            elapsed_time = time() - start_time
            print('Requests: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests / elapsed_time))
            clear_output(wait=True)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))
            if requests > 180:
                warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
                break
            page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            table = page_html.find('div', {'id': 'skater-stats'})
            table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
            for tr in table_rows:
                if tr.find('td', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap;'}) is not None:
                    player = tr.span.a.text
                    players.append(player)
                    gp = tr.find('td', {'class': 'gp'}).text
                    games_played.append(int(gp))
                    g = tr.find('td', {'class': 'g'})
                    goals.append(int(g))
                    a = tr.find('td', {'class': 'a'})
                    assists.append(a)
                    pim = tr.find('td', {'class': 'pim'})
                    penalty_minutes.append(int(pim))
                    pm = tr.find('td', {'class': 'pm'})
                    plus_minus.append(int(pm))

player_stats = pd.DataFrame({'player_name': players,
                             'gp': games_played,
                             'g': goals,
                             'a': assists,
                             'pim': penalty_minutes,
                             'plus_minus': plus_minus})

print(player_stats.info())
print(player_stats.describe())
print(player_stats.head(10))

player_stats.to_csv('CHL_player_stats.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It would be worthwhile to isolate the issue of having been banned first. Run you code using a vpn. Cryptostorm is a free VPN I have used. Or you can try taking your laptop to a coffee shop for  free "vpn," by using their IP address.

Comment: If you are trying to isolate if your IP is banned, what happens when you access the site from a web browser?

Comment: @Ian-Fogelman ... the site works fine in my browser.  I had checked that, thinking that if it was my IP then it may not work as it normally should, but everything is works like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a mispelling issue:

prospectus is misspelled in your script

elitepospects -> eliteprospects

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import time
from time import sleep
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from warnings import warn
import pandas as pd


leagues = ['whl', 'ohl', 'qmjhl']
leagues_url = [str(i) for i in leagues]
seasons = ['2005-2006', '2006-2007', '2007-2008', '2008-2009', '2009-2010',
           '2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015',
           '2016-2017', '2017-2018']
seasons_url = [str(i) for i in seasons]
pages = [str(i) for i in range(1, 5)]

players = []
games_played = []
goals = []
assists = []
penalty_minutes = []
plus_minus = []

start_time = time()
requests = 0

for league in leagues_url:
    for season in seasons_url:
        for page in pages:
            print(page)
            print('https://www.elitepospects.com/league/'
               + str(league)
               + '/stats/'
               + str(season)
               + '?sort=tp&page='
               + str(page))

            response = get('https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/'
               + str(league)
               + '/stats/'
               + str(season)
               + '?sort=tp&page='
               + str(page))
            sleep(30)
            requests += 1
            elapsed_time = time() - start_time
            print('Requests: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests / elapsed_time))
            clear_output(wait=True)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))
            if requests > 180:
                warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
                break
            page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            table = page_html.find('div', {'id': 'skater-stats'})
            table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
            for tr in table_rows:
                if tr.find('td', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap;'}) is not None:
                    player = tr.span.a.text
                    players.append(player)
                    gp = tr.find('td', {'class': 'gp'}).text
                    games_played.append(int(gp))
                    g = tr.find('td', {'class': 'g'})
                    goals.append(int(g))
                    a = tr.find('td', {'class': 'a'})
                    assists.append(a)
                    pim = tr.find('td', {'class': 'pim'})
                    penalty_minutes.append(int(pim))
                    pm = tr.find('td', {'class': 'pm'})
                    plus_minus.append(int(pm))

player_stats = pd.DataFrame({'player_name': players,
                             'gp': games_played,
                             'g': goals,
                             'a': assists,
                             'pim': penalty_minutes,
                             'plus_minus': plus_minus})

print(player_stats.info())
print(player_stats.describe())
print(player_stats.head(10))

player_stats.to_csv('CHL_player_stats.csv', index=False)
```

Edit :

I think you will find there is also a problem with finding the player tag, i also disabled the clear text to view the logging better in Jupyter Note Books.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import time
from time import sleep
#from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from warnings import warn
import pandas as pd
#from selenium import webdriver


leagues = ['whl', 'ohl', 'qmjhl']
leagues_url = [str(i) for i in leagues]
seasons = ['2005-2006', '2006-2007', '2007-2008', '2008-2009', '2009-2010',
           '2010-2011', '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015',
           '2016-2017', '2017-2018']
seasons_url = [str(i) for i in seasons]
pages = [str(i) for i in range(1, 5)]

players = []
games_played = []
goals = []
assists = []
penalty_minutes = []
plus_minus = []

start_time = time()
requests = 0

for league in leagues_url:
    for season in seasons_url:
        for page in pages:
            print(page)
            print('https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/'
               + str(league)
               + '/stats/'
               + str(season)
               + '?sort=tp&page='
               + str(page))



            response = get('https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/'
               + str(league)
               + '/stats/'
               + str(season)
               + '?sort=tp&page='
               + str(page))

            sleep(3)
            requests += 1
            elapsed_time = time() - start_time
            print('Requests: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests / elapsed_time))
            #clear_output(wait=True)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))
            if requests > 180:
                warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
                break
            page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            table = page_html.find('div', {'id': 'skater-stats'})
            table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

            #for td in table.find_all('td',{'class': 'player'}):
            #    print(td.text)

            for tr in table_rows:
                if tr.find('td', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap;'}) is not None:
                    #print(tr.s)
                    try: 
                        #player = tr.span.a.text
                        #players.append(player)
                        player = tr.find('td', {'class': 'player'}).text
                        players.append(player)
                        print(player)
                        gp = tr.find('td', {'class': 'gp'}).text
                        games_played.append(str(gp))
                        g = tr.find('td', {'class': 'g'})
                        goals.append(str(g))
                        a = tr.find('td', {'class': 'a'})
                        assists.append(a)
                        pim = tr.find('td', {'class': 'pim'})
                        penalty_minutes.append(str(pim))
                        pm = tr.find('td', {'class': 'pm'})
                        plus_minus.append(str(pm))
                    except:
                        print('X')

player_stats = pd.DataFrame({'player_name': players,
                             'gp': games_played,
                             'g': goals,
                             'a': assists,
                             'pim': penalty_minutes,
                             'plus_minus': plus_minus})

print(player_stats.info())
print(player_stats.describe())
print(player_stats.head(10))

player_stats.to_csv('CHL_player_stats.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Wow ... thank you.  Don't I feel a little dumb right now.  I really appreciate your time Ian, mucho gracias.